# Una variable, dos resultados diferentes.

Tags: c

Una pregunta, ¿porqué cuando imprimo la variable 'Edad' me sale primero el resultado bien, y luego multiplicado por 10?

Código:

```
int main ()
{

    int Beca, Edad;
    float Prom;
    char edad[2], beca; 
    int valid; 

        do
       {        
            valid = 1;
            printf ("\n Digite la edad: ");
            scanf("%2s",&edad);

            int len = strlen(edad);
            int potencias[2] = {1,10};
            printf("\nAntes del for: %d", Edad);
            for(int i = 0; i<len; i++){
                printf("\n Dentro del for %d: %d", i, Edad);

                if(isdigit(edad[i])) {
                    Edad += (edad[i]-'0') * potencias[len-i-1]; 
                    printf("\n Dentro del if: %d", Edad);
                    }else{
                        printf("No es un numero");
                        valid = 0;
                    }
                }

            if (Edad==0 || Edad>=70){
                printf("\n ENTRE ");
                printf ("\n Digite una edad valida\n\n");
                valid = 0;
            } 
            printf("\nDESPUES DEL FOR %d", Edad); 
            printf("\nDESPUES DEL FOR %d", Edad);
        }while (valid == 0);    
       // Más código 
    }
```

[image: Salida]

*Los printf de mas fueron para probar.
Gracias, de antemano!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
char edad[2]; 
scanf("%2s",&edad);
```

Si usas `scanf` con `%s`, la función terminará la cadena con un caracter nulo. Es decir, para almacenar `"14"` necesitarás 3 espacios... y tu variable únicamente admite 2. El resultado es que estás pisando el valor de otra variable. ¿cual? Pues depende del compilador y de las optimizaciones que realice. En unos casos te puede hasta llegar a funcionar y en otros te dará errores de lo más variopintos.

Si asumes que la edad es válida en el rango (1-99), entonces tendrás que usar una variable con un mínimo de 3 huecos:

```
char edad[3];
```

Comment: Estoy compilando en repl.it (compilador online), entiend lo que dices, lo cambié y aún me da el mismo resultado...

Comment: @AdalgisaFerrer Prueba con otros compiladores, como [ideone](https://ideone.com/) o [tutorialspoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_c_online.php) ... puede sea un bug de esa web